# How to exclude named pipes and sockets in Puppet?

Tags: linux, puppet

We have an application which spawns named pipes (type p) on the fly. We want to manage the other files of the directory where the pipes are spawned with Puppet. Is there a simple way to tell puppet to skip that type of file. I could ignore a couple of files, like so:

```
file {'/var/opt/OV/share/tmp':
  ensure => directory,
  recurse => true,        # enable recursive directory management
  owner => user,
  group => group,
  mode => 2775,
  ignore => 'ovcd.*',
 }
```

But as I said, I cannot determine how the pipes are named beforehand. I should really like ignore => Type p or something like that. Can this be done standardly in Puppet?

I ended up with:

```
exec { "set_perms_tmp":
  command => '/usr/bin/find /var/opt/OV/tmp ! \( -type s -o -type p \) -exec chmod 2775 {} \; -exec chown -R bin:bin /var/opt/OV/tmp/* {} \;'
}
```

Sockets and Puppet are no joy either.

Comment: From giving the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file) a cursory examination, that does not seem to be possible, sadly.

Comment: Is there any option to change the location of the named pipe?

Comment: General note, you want to add `checksum => none` to such resources, otherwise an agent run may become quite expensive (with puppet calculating each file's `md5sum`).

Comment: Sadly no, it is already a tmp directory, and I think build in the software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When something isn't builtin to file, I generally just to turn to an puppet `exec` declaration. By using find to execute whatever commands you mean by "manage files" you should be able to accomplish your goal.

Find can exclude Named Pipes:

```
   -type c
          File is of type c:

          b      block (buffered) special

          c      character (unbuffered) special

          d      directory

          p      named pipe (FIFO)

          f      regular file

          ....
```

So something like:

```
exec { "set_perms": 
  command => "/usr/bin/find /var/opt/OV/share/tmp ! -type p -exec chmod 2775 {} \;"
}
```

Comment: Ah, the pragmatic way - crude and effective ;-) I've been there, but have since found it to be better practice to have `puppet` manage a `cron` job to do just that work instead. YMMV. This may just be fine for you.